# TypeError: Error #2007

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs3

Sept 20,2012, 7:27pm GMT+8.. still having the same error even with the code "continue;"...
any other suggestion? :(

HELP the previous answers still isnt working.. :(

praticing tutorial.
im getting a error on this part of my code when the object git the catcher..

```
function moveObject(e:Event):void {
    // cycle thru objects using a for loop
    for (var i:int=objects.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        //move objects down based on speed
        objects[i].y += speed;
        objects[i].rotation += speed;
        // if objects leaves the stage
        if (objects[i].y > 400) {
            // remove it from display list
            removeChild(objects[i]);
            // remove it from the array backwards
            // remove it backwards removes all problems when looping through.
            // forward would cause confusion if you removed 5 before 4. 
            objects.splice(i, 1);

        }
        if (objects[i].hitTestObject(player.arrowS.sackC)) {
            if (objects[i].typestr == "good") {
                score += 3;
            } else {
                score -= 5;
                if (score <= 0) {
                    score = 0;
                }
            }
            trace(score);
            updateScore(score);
            removeChild(objects[i]);
            objects.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
  }
```

although the game is still working its irritating to see this.
this is the error

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
at flash.display::DisplayObject/flash.display:DisplayObject::_hitTest()
at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
at adventure_fla::MainTimeline/moveObject()
```

Comment: I guess, the error is due to trying to access after the object has been removed and spliced. Just break the loop once you removes the object from the stage.

Comment: @Frankie Roy Sanqui Niver - maybe you should show more of your code if you're still having issues.

Comment: I think I was wrong in my first comment. The error is `Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.` means the display object you are providing to the `hitTestObject, ie) player.arrowS.sackC` becomes `null` sometimes. Are you removing it or moving to another frame or scene when the enter frame is listening. Please check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through an array,  and if `if (objects[i].y > 400) {` is true, then you splice that element out of your array, so `objects[i]` is now null.

Then you go and do `if (objects[i].hitTestObject(player.arrowS.sackC)) {` but if the first coniditon was true, `objects[i]` no longer has a value so you get the posted error.

What you want to do, is not break out of the loop, but rather use the `continue` keyword so the loop moves on to the next item.

```
if (objects[i].y > 400) {
        // remove it from display list
        removeChild(objects[i]);
        // remove it from the array backwards
        // remove it backwards removes all problems when looping through.
        // forward would cause confusion if you removed 5 before 4. 
        objects.splice(i, 1);
        continue; //abandon the rest of this loop cycle (since objects[i] is now null), and move on to the next loop cycle, so the below code doesn't execute for the current i
}
```

In addition to the above, you should also check that your `player.arrowS.sackC` isn't null:

```
if(player && player.arrowS && player.arrowS.sackC && objects[i].hitTestObject(player.arrowS.sackC))
```

Comment: If you are removing an element from an array, the array is getting refreshed. That is the element in the next index moved down or fills the index position of the removed element and it continues till it reaches the end of the array. So It won't be `null` unless `i = objects.length -1;`

Comment: sorry sir, i find it hard to understand.. can you just put the code that i must replace in order to correct the error? thank you

Comment: @Moorthy - He is iterating through the array backwards, so yes, it will be null (or rather `undefined`).  If you don't think so, just try it.

Comment: @Frankie Roy Sanqui Niver - It could also be that your `player.arrowS.sackC` is null.  before your loop, try tracing `trace("player:",player,"arrowS",player.arrowS,"sackC",player.arrowS.sackC);` and see if any come back null

Comment: @Frankie Roy Sanqui Niver - added another snippet at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Does someone care to explain the -1 ?

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices the object is properly traced so therefore it isnt the one causing the problem.. should i just post the whole code? :(

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the value of a particular variable is null at runtime.Check hitTestObject value at different locations if it becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the object and work from that reference

```
 function moveObject(e:Event):void {
    // cycle thru objects using a for loop

    if(player.arrowS.sackC){
      var currentObject:MovieClip;
      for (var i:int=objects.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
          //move objects down based on speed
          currentObject = objects[i] as MovieClip;
          currentObject.y += speed;
          currentObject.rotation += speed;
          // if objects leaves the stage
          if (currentObject.y > 400) {
              // remove it from display list
              removeChild(currentObject);
              // remove it from the array backwards
              // remove it backwards removes all problems when looping through.
              // forward would cause confusion if you removed 5 before 4. 
              objects.splice(i, 1);
              continue;// go to next iteration of loop
          }
          if (currentObject.hitTestObject(player.arrowS.sackC)) {
              if (currentObject.typestr == "good") {
                  score += 3;
              } else {
                  score -= 5;
                  if (score <= 0) {
                      score = 0;
                  }
              }
              trace(score);
              updateScore(score);
              removeChild(currentObject);
              objects.splice(i, 1);
              continue;// go to next iteration of loop
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: sir somehow its giving this error...
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: @FrankieRoySanquiNiverba : It's because he is assigning the display object stored in the array to a object. If the all the objects are movieclip then declare the `currentObject` like `var currentObject:MovieClip;` and while assign `currentObject = objects[i] as MovieClip`. This rectify the error you were commented

Comment: even if i change those.. the error will be the same again..

 TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
at flash.display::DisplayObject/flash.display:DisplayObject::_hitTest()
at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
at adventure_fla::MainTimeline/moveObject()

Answer (score 0):

```
function moveObject(e:Event):void {
    // cycle thru objects using a for loop
    for (var i:int=objects.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        //move objects down based on speed
        objects[i].y += speed;
        objects[i].rotation += speed;
        // if objects leaves the stage
        if (objects[i].y > 400) {
            // remove it from display list
            removeChild(objects[i]);
            // remove it from the array backwards
            // remove it backwards removes all problems when looping through.
            // forward would cause confusion if you removed 5 before 4. 
            objects.splice(i, 1);
            //once an element is spliced from the array the array is getting refreshed
            //so to avoid accessing empty array(ie, after the last element is removed) in the next if condition, the loop has breaked here
            //Don't worry about return statement as the Enter frame listener function calls till the listener has been removed
            return;
        }
        if (objects[i].hitTestObject(player.arrowS.sackC)) {
            if (objects[i].typestr == "good") {
                score += 3;
            } else {
                score -= 5;
                if (score <= 0) {
                    score = 0;
                }
            }
            trace(score);
            updateScore(score);
            removeChild(objects[i]);
            objects.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `player.arrowS.sackC` not null? Please check that and update your comment to help you better.

Comment: It would be better if you(who downvote my answer) give the reason for downvoting it. It will help me to improve myself more.

Answer (score 0):

sir i got the answer to solve my problem it isnt the code but in the animation that i made for the character, because it contains keyframe that both have the instance name sackC :D

i know it is not the professional way o do the coding but what can i say.. im just a beginner..

though thank you all for your assistance ..

Comment: You should still add the continue statements as they are needed for you code to perform in the way that you expect.  You said that your sackC was tracing out fine, were you adding the check in your if statement that has the hitTest?